# Output voltage of op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I need to find the output at the amplifier in the first column. The row with the grey arrow indicates that we have switched to ground, from what was initially Vref. I thought I could treat it as a voltage divider with R_c and the row resistor as the terms.

It's a circuit from a research paper, but the equation is not provided.

So what is the single sensor reading? Which is essentially the voltage from the amplifier in column one and the second to last row... I'm really just trying to derive an equation wherein I can solve for the variable row resistor.

[image]

Comment: You've forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: fixed? I forgot to attach the image.

Comment: It's not clear form your post where you're getting stuck (because you haven't asked a question). But if you ignore switch resistance then you can treat each column as a simple inverting summing amplifier.

Comment: Ofc if you can't ignore the switch resistance then it gets a bit more ... interesting ...

Comment: I can't ignore the switch resistance. I'm eventually trying to solve it given that I know Rc and Rg and Vref.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it a bit more, the voltage on each column is Vref (due to opamp negative feedback bringing the - input to the same potential as the + input). So that means that there's no current flow through any sensor not on the activated row - so ignore all those. Then, since every sensor on the activated row has Vref on one side and the switch on the other, you treat them as being in parallel to work out the switch current. With the switch current and switch resistance you can work out the actual voltage the row is at above 0V, then it's back to inverting summing opamp.

Comment: It's just a voltage divider. You ignore all the other nodes except the one being activated in the array.  What the internal R does depends on your sensor array.

Comment: I agree that all the other rows can be omitted. So you are saying that it is indeed a voltage divider with V_o = V_ref * (R_sensor /(R_sensor + R_c))?

Comment: That's only true if you ignore switch resistance. If your switch resistance is not zero, then the voltage across a sensor is not Vref, it's (Vref - Vswitch), and Vswitch depends on the other sensors in the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Op-amps have three basic properties: near infinite input impedance, near infinite open loop gain, and a virtual short between the two input terminals **(when used with negative feedback)**. The short causes Vref to appear at the inverting (-) terminal of each op-amp. As a result, no current is flowing through Rc. However, when a switch is enabled, each of the sensor array resistors in that row can now conduct current. Where does this current come from? The op-amp's output through the feedback path. The final output from the analog switch comes from the current being drawn due to the sensor multiplied by Rg in the feedback path of the op-amp. In an equation:

V(read) = Rg * Vref/R(sensor)

Comment: "*Op-amps have ... a virtual short between the two input terminals*" **when used with negative feedback**. You might want to clarify that. Many of our readers get caught out with, for example, Schmitt triggers.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the update!